# After sliding in next flexslider slide, css animation is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

In every flexslider list I have a div which is named class="txt",

and so I need to animate this txt class in every flexslider's list example :

```
<div class='flexslider'>
<ul>
<li><div class="txt">lorem ipsum</div></li>
<li><div class="txt">lorem ipsum</div></li>
<li><div class="txt">lorem ipsum</div></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

But only the first class="txt" in list of flexslider is animating by css below, others in list whenever I click next are not getting the animation, what should i do ?

Here is the animation code I'm using for txt class :

```
-webkit-animation: aniload 1s;
-moz-animation: aniload 1s;
-ms-animation: aniload 1s;
-o-animation: aniload 1s;
animation: aniload 1s;

@-webkit-keyframes aniload {
  from {-webkit-transform:translate(0px, 1000px)}
  to   {-webkit-transform:translate(0px, 0px)}
}
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/o3yftL2o/

Comment: @akshay 

every list <li> on flexslider is full width at my site, so the problem is when the second <li> kicks in, it wont work the animation.. In ur example all the lists are getting animated in the same time, in my case they all have to get animated one by one

Answer (score 0):

You can delay your other animations http://jsfiddle.net/o3yftL2o/2/

```
.txt_a{
-webkit-animation: aniload 1s;
-moz-animation: aniload 1s;
-ms-animation: aniload 1s;
-o-animation: aniload 1s;
animation: aniload 1s;
-webkit-animation-delay:1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes aniload {
  0% {-webkit-transform:translate(0px, 1000px)}
 100%  {-webkit-transform:translate(0px, 0px)}
}

 .txt_b{
-webkit-animation: aniload2 1s;
-moz-animation: aniload2 1s;
-ms-animation: aniload2 1s;
-o-animation: aniload2 1s;
 animation: aniload2 1s;
-webkit-animation-delay:.5s;
}

 @-webkit-keyframes aniload2 {
 from {-webkit-transform:translate(0px, 1000px)}
to   {-webkit-transform:translate(0px, 0px)}
}
 .txt_c{
-webkit-animation: aniload3 1s;
-moz-animation: aniload3 1s;
-ms-animation: aniload3 1s;
-o-animation: aniload3 1s;
animation: aniload3 1s;
-webkit-animation-delay:0s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes aniload3 {
 from {-webkit-transform:translate(0px, 1000px)}
to   {-webkit-transform:translate(0px, 0px)}
```

}

Comment: well i can delay but what if the user Preses the "NEXT" button in flexslider :D ? it wont animate

Comment: @Tahi what next button?